# Python GUI Plot axis and title labels

Tags: python, user-interface, bar-chart, axis-labels

I am having trouble labeling the axis and giving my plot a title. I am using QT Designer to create a ui file.  Can someone please help?

```py
class MplCanvas(FigureCanvas):

    def __init__(self, parent=None, width=6, height=5, dpi=100):
        fig = Figure(figsize=(width, height), dpi=dpi)
        self.axes = fig.add_subplot(111)
        super(MplCanvas, self).__init__(fig)


    x_pos = np.arange(len(All_Runs_Names))
    # plot figure
    sc = MplCanvas(self, width=5, height=4, dpi=100)

    # assign data here
    sc.axes.bar(x_pos, All_Runs_Total_Errors, color = (0.5,0.1,0.5,0.6))
    
    # toolbar and layout creation
    toolbar = NavigationToolbar(sc, self.MyWindow)
    layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
    layout.addWidget(toolbar)
    layout.addWidget(sc)
    self.MyWindow.plotWidget.setLayout(layout)
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using `add_subplot`, look at [this](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/subplots_axes_and_figures/figure_title.html) to know how to set title and labels to your subplot. If you can't see the plot title you might have to [`adjust_subplots`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.subplots_adjust.html).

Also, consider using QtAgg backend (version dependent on pyqt version you use) for the reasons described in [here](https://www.pythonguis.com/tutorials/plotting-matplotlib/).

Cheers.

PS.
For my own purposes I did something similar to this, although using `add_axes` instead of `add_subplot`:

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('Qt5Agg')
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg import FigureCanvasQTAgg
from matplotlib.figure import Figure

from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, uic
import sys

class Window(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Window, self).__init__()
        uic.loadUi('path_to_file\\file.ui', self)
        
        self.my_chart = MplCanvas(self)
        layout = self.mychart_layout
        layout.addWidget(self.my_chart)

        self.something_to_do([1,2,3,4],[1,2,3,4])

        self.show()

    def something_to_do(self, xdata, ydata):
        self.my_chart.axes.set_title("title")
        self.my_chart.axes.set_position([0.07,0.1,0.87,0.8]) # here is repositioning of the axes
        # if the default (in the MplCanvas class) cannot reveal the title set
        # definitely something you should tweak.
        line, = self.my_chart.axes.plot(xdata, ydata) # line handle for updating the line during runtime


class MplCanvas(FigureCanvasQTAgg):

    def __init__(self, parent=None, width=5, height=4, dpi=100):
        fig = Figure(figsize=(width, height), dpi=dpi)
        self.axes = fig.add_axes([0.07,0.165,0.925,0.83]) # initial rectangle for any canvas' axes ([left, bottom, width, height])
        self.axes.set_ylabel('y label')
        self.axes.set_xlabel('x label')
        super(MplCanvas, self).__init__(fig)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Window()
    app.exec_()
```